# Maximum sum of lengths of non-overlapping contiguous subarrays

Tags: c++, arrays, post-increment

I'm trying to implement [amazon](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-experience-set-376-campus-internship/) interview question.

> ```
> Find the maximum sum of lengths of non-overlapping contiguous subarrays with k as the maximum element.
> Ex: Array: {2,1,4,9,2,3,8,3,4} and k = 4
> Ans: 5
> {2,1,4} => Length = 3
> {3,4} => Length = 2
> So, 3 + 2 = 5 is the answer
> ```

I have implement program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int a[] = {2,1,4,9,2,3,8,3,4,2};
        int cnt = 0, i = 0, j = 0, ele, k = 4;
        int tmp = 0, flag = 0;

        ele = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

        for(j = 0; j < ele; )
        {
                i = j;
              //while( i < ele && a[i++] <= k) //It's working fine
                while(a[i] <= k && i++ < ele)  // It's not work
                {
                        cnt++;
                        cout<<"while"<<endl;
                }

                while(j < i)
                {
                        if(a[j++] == k)
                        {
                                flag = 1;
                        }
                }

                if(flag == 1)
                {
                        tmp += cnt;
                        flag = 0;
                }
                cnt = 0;
                j = i;
        }
        cout<<"count : "<<tmp<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

In my program, I used

```
while( i < ele && a[i++] <= k)
```

It's working fine and gives correct output.

But, If I use

```
while(a[i] <= k && i++ < ele)
```

then my program is stuck. Why?

Comment: [OT]: You may simplify your code like [that](http://ideone.com/fj8JvB)

Answer (score 3):

With `while(a[i] <= k && i++ < ele)` you can actually go out of bounds of the array `a`, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

If `i` is the last index of the array, then `i++ < ele` is actually `true` (because the postfix `++` operator returns the *old* value before incrementing), and then in the loop `i` will be out of bounds.

Undefined behavior is, well, *undefined* and could mean that just about anything could happen. From crashes to infinite or stuck loops.

A better solution would be to use *prefix* increment instead, as in `++i < ele`.

Comment: isnt is already UB, because `i++` and `a[i]` appears in the same expression?

Comment: @tobi303 No, the left-hand side is sequenced before the right-hand side of a `&&` or `||` expression (see e.g. [this evaluation order reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), especially [rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules) 6).

Answer (score 0):

The different between `while( i < ele && a[i++] <= k)` and `while(a[i] <= k && i++ < ele)` is:
`while( i < ele && a[i++] <= k)` will increment `i` first and get value later but `while(a[i] <= k && i++ < ele)` will compare `i` and `ele` first and increment `i` later.

So in your code, when program run out of `while(a[i] <= k && i++ < ele)` , `i` is equal `3`, but `while( i < ele && a[i++] <= k)` is equal to `4`. That's why the problem caused